# Regex Pattern to Match Currency Format - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am newbie to javascript and struggling to write regex pattern for the requirement

2,4  = 24.00

2.4  =  2.40

2.4.5 = 2.40

2.5,5 = 2.50

2,5.7 = 25.70

45.56.34 = 45.56

13.,0 = 13.00

13,.0 = 13.00

Only digits and comma and dot are allowed.
it doesn't matter how they enter
But i have to convert this into proper currency format
xxx,xxx,xxx,xx.xx

edited: to clarify doubts

Comment: `2,4 = 24.00`, but `2,5.7 = 2.50`. I don't understand something.

Comment: You have not given enough information. For example, why does `2,5.7` become `2.50` instead of `25.70`, and why does `2.4.5` become `2.40` instead of `2.45`

Comment: Seems like there are a few conflicting requirements here.

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
var input  = '2,4';
var output = parseFloat( input.replace(",", ".").replace("..", ".") ).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: A few of these examples will take more work than that, eg 13.,0 and 45.56.34

Comment: Fair do's - wasn't expecting parseFloat to handle 45.56.34 mostly. +1

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the below web site you will find the Regex you are looking for

http://www.regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3